# Disabling dropdownlist inside a gridview based on value selected on another dropdownlist inside the gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, datagrid

I have two dropdown lists inside the  gridview, namely ddonsiteoffsite and ddhours. Now what I want is if the selectedtext of ddonsiteoffsite is "onsite" the ddhours should be disabled. I tried the following code snippet, but it's not disabling the ddhours.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="      OnSite/OffSite" >   
                <ItemTemplate>   
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOnsiteOffside" runat="server" onchange="ToggleOnOff(this)"><asp:ListItem Text = "Offsite" Value="Offsite"></asp:ListItem>        
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "Onsite" Value="Onsite"></asp:ListItem> 
                      </asp:DropDownList>   
                </ItemTemplate>   
            </asp:TemplateColumn>   
             <asp:TemplateColumn>   
                <ItemTemplate>   
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddhours" runat="server">   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "1" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "3" Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "4" Value="4" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "5" Value="5" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "6" Value="6" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "7" Value="7" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "8" Value="8" ></asp:ListItem>   
                        <asp:ListItem Text = "9" Value="9" ></asp:ListItem>   
                    </asp:DropDownList>   
                </ItemTemplate>   
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

and the corresponding JavaScript I am using is:

```
function ToggleOnOff(ddonoff)    
  {      

     var row = chk.parentNode.parentNode;              
     if(ddonoff.value=="Onsite")    
     {           
          row.getElementsByTagName("ddhours")[0].disabled = true;                   
     }   
     else   
          row.getElementsByTagName("ddhours")[0].disabled = false;                    
 }
```

How can I achieve this using JavaScript or jQuery? I'm not understanding where I went wrong.

Comment: I have retagged gridview to datagrid as its asp:templatecolumn

Comment: please mark as answer the post that helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this.

```
function ToggleOnOff(ddonoff) {
    $(ddonoff)
        .parent()// parent of ddl is td
        .next()// gives the next td 
        .find('select')// finds a select element in that td
        .attr('disabled', (ddonoff.value == "Onsite") ? 'disabled' : '');//enable-disable
}
```

OR

```
function ToggleOnOff(ddonoff) {
    $(ddonoff)
        .parent()//td
        .parent()//tr
        .find('select[id*="ddhours"]')//select by id
        .attr('disabled', (ddonoff.value == "Onsite") ? 'disabled' : '');//disable-enable
}
```

Method 2 works even if the two columns are not next to each other.

Dependency: [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Comment: hey that worked ... can u explain the mechanism behind it ??? how did it actually worked ???  @ naveen ?

Comment: @joy: I have given the explanation as comments

Comment: hey thanks :) for the ans :) it really helped :) ... now i can use this to handle any gridviewtemplates....

Comment: This will not be a good solution as you are dealing with invalid HTML(having more than one element with the same id).

Comment: @rahul: what are you thinking pal? Wont datagrid, gridview auto rename ids to make them unique?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having more than one element with the same id then it will be an invalid HTML document. Remove the ids and give it a name.

Something like this

```
$("select[name='ddOnsiteOffsideName']").change(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    var hoursSelectBox = parent.find("select[name='hoursName']");
    if (hoursSelectBox.val() === "Onsite") {
        hoursSelectBox.attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

In your code you are using `row.getElementsByTagName("ddhours")`. This will fetch all the elements with the tag name `ddhours' which will not be correct in this case.

Comment: no the thing is it would b per row of the gridview..... per row i hav the same ddhour and ddOnsiteOffsite now i want the attributes to b added for each row.....